# First run run after install

Tags: android

In Symbian, if we set a parameter frri, we can make the appmanager to run the new application on completion of download and installation. Do we have any feature as such in android so that application will start as soon as it gets installed on to device.

Thx.

Answer (score 5):

No, that is not possible. You must wait for the user to start your application, or for Android to broadcast some Intent for which you have a manifest-registered receiver established.

Comment: Can another application which is already running listen the broadcast event and start the new Installed application after download